# Should local SQL Server edition be the same as host's edition?

Tags: sql-server

I am about to upload an ecommerce website in ASP.NET 3.5 to a host. I want to upload my database which is SQL Server 2008 Express Edition to the host where I am sure the SQL Server edition is not Express. So I wonder if I upload the .BAK file and then restore It via the admin control panel, my database on the host will be express edition or it will change to the host's edition automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Edition will not usually have any affect on a database, unless you are using features in the database that may not be available across all Editions of SQL Server. However since you are going from Express to a likely higher Edition (Standard/Enterprise) you probably will not have any issues.

Comment: thank you for your answer ! so I want to know uploading express edtion causes to have an express edition database on the host ?! or the database edition changes to the host's edition automatically in upload and restore way of uploading the db ?

Comment: There is no such thing as an "express edition database". Databases are based on the database version. If you are running SQL Server 2008 R2 Express and your host is running SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise, nothing is going to change.